# Need info on json script

Tags: jquery, json

In the following code what is function(payload) doing??Actually i put an alert in function(payload){} i so not see the alert

**EDIT**

Also i see that there is a repose from the server but why is that i do not see an alert here

```
  $("form#form").submit(function(){
     $.post(url,
        {
          time: timestamp,
          action: "postmsg",
          message: $("#msg").val()
        },
        function(payload) {
          alert('1');
          $("#msg").val(""); // clean out contents of input field.
        },
        'json'
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with weird indentation I'm able to understand what's going on with my crazy JavaScript skills.

Your `function(payload)` is a callback to the `$.post` request. The callback will be called once the AJAX `$.post` request is done.

You probably don't see it run because `url` is returning a bad status code. The `$.post` callback will only run if the `url` is accessible with a correct status code.

For debugging try accessing `url` just from your browser, and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

It will run when the HTTP response comes back from the server

… unless the browser leaves the current page first, which it will do as the you aren't [stopping the normal behaviour of the submit button](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/).